# Entity 5/6 Model first: do I have to manually map entities?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

When I first created my .edmx, I added a single entity. I then selected "Generate database from model" and successfully created my database and did some testing with that single entity/table and some dummy data.

I'm working on my model again, and I've added a number of other tables and associations. When I select "Generate database from model" now, I get lots of errors about things not being mapped (including the new scalar properties on my original entity), as well as a message box showing the following error:

> Expression of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection' cannot be
>   used for return type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection'.

Why would generating the database work the first time with a single entity (without me ever explicitly declaring any mapping for table or columns), but not with multiple entities added after the original? Do I need to manually map everything (doesn't seem likely, but I must be missing something)?

Comment: Close your solution and re-start the visual studio. This worked for me and many others, as i can see the thread. Still clueless, how it worked,

Answer (score 36):

I had this exact same error in EF6

```
Expression of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection' cannot be used for return type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection'.
```

Saving and restarting Visual Studio fixed it for me.

Comment: Ok, that was not quite obvious. But this Solution worked out. Thank you, Sir :)

Comment: Does not work with VS2015. The problem only goes away if you downgrade EntityFramework to version 6.2.0 or lower.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not sure why this worked, I updated from the database, and then, inexplicably, updating the other way worked again. If subsequent answers could explain why in greater detail, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Change version of EntityFramework nuget package. Newer ones don't work with older versions of Visual Studio.